# How principal component analysis ensures component orthogonality when using zero co-variance as the restriction to maximize variance?

Tags: statistics, transformation, orthogonality

I am currently learning the mathematics behind PCA and I found when PCA maximizes variance to find out the 2nd, 3rd, ... components, it uses zero co-variance as the restriction, as shown below,

[image]

However, I believe PCA is also an orthogonal transformation. **I am very puzzled by how the zero co-variance restriction can ensure the orthogonality**? Any hint or recommendation of reading, lecture video is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure this out! I post the answer and hope it might be helpful for someone else. Two other questions I asked related to this one are

1. [A question about co-variance of two linear combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216130/a-question-about-co-variance-of-two-linear-combinations)
2. [Why the principal components correspond to the eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217862/why-the-principal-components-correspond-to-the-eigenvalues)

By the first question, I figured out that ${\mathop{\rm cov}} ({{\bf{a}}^{\rm{T}}}{\bf{X}},{{\bf{b}}^{\rm{T}}}{\bf{X}}) = {{\bf{a}}^{\rm{T}}}\rm{var}({\bf{X}}){\bf{b}}$.

By the second question, I figured out that the the loadings of each principal component are orthogonal eigenvectors of the co-variance matrix $\rm{var}({\bf{X}})$. Note that co-variance matrix is a real-valued symmetric matrix, which must have $n$ orthogonal eigenvectors.

As a result, suppose $\bf{a}_1^\rm{T}$ and $\bf{a}_2^\rm{T}$ are loadings of two principal components, then ${\mathop{\rm cov}} ({\bf{a}}_1^{\rm{T}}{\bf{X}},{\bf{a}}_2^{\rm{T}}{\bf{X}}) = {\bf{a}}_1^{\rm{T}}\rm{var}({\bf{X}}){{\bf{a}}_2}{\rm{ = }}{\bf{a}}_1^{\rm{T}}\lambda {{\bf{a}}_2}{\rm{ = }}\lambda {\bf{a}}_1^{\rm{T}}{{\bf{a}}_2}{\rm{ = }}0$, which completes the proof.